# Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null

Tags: php, wordpress

Can you please tell me what I did wrong there:

```
$popular_posts_args = new wp_query( array(
                                'post_type'         => 'blog',
                                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                                'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                                //'meta_value'        => '1',
                                'order'             => 'DESC',
                                'meta_key'          => 'my_post_viewed',
                                'posts_per_page'    => $number
                                )
                            );
query_posts( $popular_posts_loop ); 
 while( $popular_posts_loop->have_posts() ): 
      $popular_posts_loop->the_post();
wp_reset_query();
```

It's this line :

```
query_posts( $popular_posts_loop ); 
 while( $popular_posts_loop->have_posts() ): 
        $popular_posts_loop->the_post();
```

Comment: Well, that's not how to write a [`while`](http://php.net/while) loop, for starters...

Comment: Sorry I'm more of a newbie

Answer (score -1):

Oops, sorry guys I just realized that I had

$popular_posts_loop

Instead of $popular_posts_args

It's good now !